# Scale image height automatic by fixed width in ItemStyle.xsl?

Tags: item-styles

I am using SharePoint 2010.

I have a content query web part and have created my own `ItemStyle.xsl`. In this item style I have some title, description and image. This image has a fixed width and height of 150px. Is it possible to set only a fixed width of 150px and scaled automatic height?

Comment: Please post the xsl that you use to render the img tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to resize the image proportionally via CSS

Lets assume the following xsl is used for image rendering in `ItemStyle.xsl`:

```
<img class="image" src="{$SafeImageUrl}" title="{@ImageUrlAltText}">
</img>
```

then the following Css could be used to resize the image proportionally:

```
img.image {
    width:150px; 
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Someone told me, if I leave the height and set only the width it will automaticly scale the height. Is that true?

Comment: It is better to set height:auto explicitly. The key is to use height:auto to override any height="..." attribute already present on the image.